# Удалить использованный файл

Tags: python, файлы

При работе программы (в google colab) загружаю файл с компьютера. Использую данные.

Затем, необходимо загрузить новый файл с таким же названием.

В памяти сохраняются оба с именами: 'Values.csv' и 'Values(1).csv'

Как можно удалить использованный файл 'Values.csv', чтобы новый при загрузке сохранился под тем же именем, без ...(1) ?

```
files.upload()
!ls
'Values(1).csv' 
'Values.csv'

Data = pd.read_csv('Values.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Сам нашел.:

```
import os
os.remove('Values.csv')
```